# Virtualenv: can't create virtualenv: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'

Tags: python, virtualenv

This happens when attempting to update the python installation in my virtualenv OR when creating a new virtualenv:

```
[marcintustin@localhost oneclickrep]$ virtualenv --always-copy --clear --python=/usr/bin/python oneclickcosvirt/ 
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python
Deleting tree oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7
Not deleting oneclickcosvirt/bin
New python executable in oneclickcosvirt/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 821, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 956, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1377, in install_python
    shutil.copyfile(py_executable_base, full_pth)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'
[marcintustin@localhost oneclickrep]$
```

The result is consistently the above. `/usr/bin/python` exists and is working very nicely (it's also the python picked up by `which`). What's the cause here?

Edit: Using virtualenv version 1.10.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with virtualenv. Using the `--always-copy` flag triggers copying behaviour, which is broken. There are bug reports and patches already submitted.

The line `shutil.copyfile(py_executable_base, full_pth)` should be `shutil.copyfile(py_executable, full_pth)`.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting this answer.  It saved me some time.

Comment: @brma No prob. It's frustrating that a new release hasn't been rushed out, as it is literally a one-line fix.